# Replace values in an array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a scenario like this. Say: let a = [2,5,6] and let b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. Array b is displayed in boxes and revealed when one clicks any of the boxes. What I am trying to do is, when one clicks on any box and the value is the same as any value in array a, I replace the value with other unique values and if they're not the same I display as it is.
e.g. If I click a box that has a value of 2 or 5 or 6 i replace the values with the other values.

A minimal example is:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    a: [2,5,6],
    b: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  },
  methods: {
    replaceNumber() {
      // function to replace the values
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.numbers {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Numbers:</h2>
  <br/>
  <ul class="numbers">
    <li v-for="num in a">
      {{num}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
  
  <template>
    <button @click="replaceNumber" v-for="number in b">
    {{ number }}
    </button>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I've provided a scenario

Comment: looks like you're nearly there, replaceNumber needs to be passed 'number' as an argument. Also remember that arrays need to be manipulated in a specific way to maintain reactivity, see: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf()` to locate the position of the element you want to replace.

Then use `splice()` together with the index you got to remove that element.

Then use `splice()` again to insert a new value to the same index.

Check the documentation of each method above to understand their syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with random numbers if found in first array i.e `a`

```js
var a = [2,5,6] 
 var b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
 a.forEach(function(e){
    $("#aDiv").append(`<h2>${e}</h2>`);
 })
 
  b.forEach(function(e){
    $("#bDiv").append(`<h2 class="seconddiv">${e}</h2>`);
 });
 
 $(".seconddiv").on('click',function(){
    let val= $(this).html();
    if(a.includes(parseInt(val))){
      var  uniqueNo = 0;
       do {
          uniqueNo=getRandomInt(0,10);
       }
        while (a.includes(parseInt(uniqueNo)));
       $(this).html(uniqueNo);
    }
 })
 
let getRandomInt= (x,y)=>x+(y-x+1)*crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0]/2**32|0
```

```css
#aDiv,#bDiv{
 color:yellow;
 background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maindiv">
     <div   id="aDiv">
  
     </div>
    <div id="bDiv" style="margin-top:50px;">
  
     </div>
</div>
```